# Execute functions based on input in Python

Tags: python-2.7

Python beginner: I would like to take input from the user, and based on the input, multiple functions will be executed:

```
def func1():
    'This is function 1'
def func2():
    'This is function 2'
def func3():
    'This is function 3'

funcDict = {'A': func1, 'B': func2, 'C':func3}

response = raw_input()
```

So if the user inputs the string 'A,B' , func1 and func2 will be executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your response to check whether that value is in the response, you can do this by checkig whether A, B, or C is in the string using if statements.

```
If "A" in response:
    func1()
If "B" in response:
    func2()
If "C" in response:
    func3()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways this could be done. 
The first step would be to validate the user input.
This could be done by checking if all the letters the user inputs are in the funcDict.

```
commands = response.split(",") # Split string on "," and return a list
valid = all([i in functDict for i in commands]) # check all commands are in funcDict
```

Then you could iterate of the commands and execute the corresponding function.

```
for command in commands:
    funcDict[command]()
```